# AjaxToolkit error in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am using Visual Studio 2010. I installed AjaxToolkit for .NET 3.5 framework. The installation worked fine. I added a new tab called Ajax Tool kit and installed it.

In a new web form in my web application, I added a `ScriptManager` and added the following

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="asp" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit"%>
```

On testing the page, I got the below error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'AjaxControlToolkit' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I tried changing the name of `ScriptManager` to "ToolkitScriptManager" but I still got the error.

How should I reference Ajax Tool kit?

Please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Did you right click on the project and "Add Reference". Then choose the AjaxControllToolkit.dll that you downloaded?

Comment: Thank you. I didn't do this step.